# My eclipse is not creating android activity and xml layout file

Tags: android, eclipse, android-activity, sdk, eclipse-kepler

I have updated my sdk and adt to rev 23. Since then my eclipse stopped creating acivity and xml files. I have tried everything but still no success.

Please help me resolve this issue.

Comment: You can always add an Activity to your project (make sure it's in your manifest to)

Comment: But if it not creating any .java or .xml files what is the use of getting into manifest ?

Comment: Any Activity that you want to use in your project must be defined in your manifest.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem I think that new version has problems . So you have to create new xml file and java class separately and refer from class to xml

Answer (score 0):

If create an empty activity then it works but not for any other type of activity is created.